# How to calculate total records after grouping based on certain column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

[image: Requirement]

Attached the query:

```
    select abc.acc_entry_status account_status,count(abc.acc_entry_status) count from (
    select xlasl.application_short_name short_name, 
           xlasl.application_name source,
           to_char(xtl.transaction_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') trans_date,
           xth.char1 event_type,
           xtl.application_id application_id, 
           xtl.event_id event_id, 
           xtl.line_number line_number,
           xth.transaction_number transaction_number,
           to_char(xth.creation_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') creation_date,
           aeh.gl_transfer_status_code gl_transfer_status,
           aeh.ACCOUNTING_ENTRY_STATUS_CODE acc_entry_status, 
            to_char(aeh.gl_transfer_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') gl_transfer_date,
           aeh.period_name period_name
    from xla_transaction_headers xth, 
         xla_transaction_lines xtl, 
         xla_ae_headers aeh,
         xla_subledgers_vl xlasl
    where xth.application_id=xtl.application_id
        and xth.event_id=xtl.event_id
        and xth.event_id=aeh.event_id
        and xlasl.application_id=xth.application_id
        and xlasl.application_type_code='C'
            and aeh.parent_ae_header_id is null
        and xlasl.application_name=:p_source
        and trunc(xth.creation_date)=to_date(Substr(:p_creation_date,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD'))  abc
    group by acc_entry_status
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  You should fix this query and learn proper SQL syntax for your future queries.

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
with q as (
      <your query here, hopefully fixed to use proper syntax
     )
select sum(case when account_status = 'I' then count else 0 end) as Invalid,
       sum(case when account_status = 'F' then count else 0 end) as Failed,
       sum(count) as total   
from q
where account_status in ('I', 'F')
```

Comment: The query was very likely generated automatically by some application, probably one owned by Oracle itself. The application uses Oracle join syntax, not our OP in this thread. (I know for a fact that PeopleSoft behaves that way.) Take your fight up to Oracle and the other app vendors, not the OP.